# Macro to locate heading title "Branch"

Tags: excel, vba

I receive multiple Excel reports daily. Each report will have a column titled Branch.

Example:
Tracking report will have Branch located at column D

Sales report will have Branch located at column J

Summary report will have Branch located at column C

I currently have a macro that place a filter.

I would like to enhance the macro to locate "Branch" and filter it by  "Texas"

Appreciate if you can show me how can I do so.

Thank you.

Edited: formatting

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to your problem. @BigBen points to one of them which would work if there is a column caption "Branch" in each report **and** the row number is always the same. You just find the column with either `Find` or `Match` and use that column in your filtering macro.

However, what if one of the above criteria isn't given, meaning there are different captions for the same column or the captions appear in different rows? In that case you have the choice of two ways by which you might proceed.

1. Identify the document (perhaps by its title in A1) and then associate the document with the known column number.
2. Loop through all the columns an cells and check each one for contents. For example, you might search for a branch name (or several) in columns D, J and C and the one where the name is found is the column listing branches. Again, such a check could be done very fast with either VBA's `Find` or `Application.Match` functions.

If you want to enhance your existing macro to filter by "Texas" you need to post your macro in a separate question.